# How to get custom URL routes property_id in wp php plugin?

Tags: urls

```
    // route
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'wpse26388_rewrites_init') );
    add_filter( 'query_vars', array($this, 'wpse26388_query_vars') );

    function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'properties/([0-9]+)/?$',
            'index.php?pagename=properties&property_id=$matches[1]',
            'top' );
    }
    
    function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
        $query_vars[] = 'property_id';
        return $query_vars;
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question, and explain your problem better. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, now I can understand this problem.

Answer (score 0):

get property_id to URL: 'index.php?properties/123' (index.php?pagename=properties&property_id=$matches[1])

$property_id = get_query_var( 'property_id', 1 );
output : 123